# how to display array elements php

Tags: php, arrays, global

For example; in PHP the auto-global `$_SERVER`. How do I display the elements or keys that it has?

I am unable to find out how online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$keys = array_keys($somearray);
```

Is that what you're looking for? Or are you just looking for `$somearray['somekey']`?

Answer (score 0):

For debugging I assume?

There are a couple ways, but I always do something like this:

```
die(print_r($_SERVER));
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into [var_dump()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and [print_r](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).  Both options should provide what you're looking for without having additional clarification for your request.